# Include Grandchildren in EF Query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Given the object hierarchy

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual GrandChild GrandChild { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the DB context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

One can include children and grandchildren using Lambda syntax (`using System.Data.Entity`) like this:

```
using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
{
    var hierarchy = 
        from p in ctx.Parents.Include(p => p.Child.GrandChild) select p;
}
```

The Lambda syntax prevents breaking the query if the class names are subsequently altered.  However, if `Parent` has an `ICollection<Child>` like this instead:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Lambda syntax no longer works.  Instead, one can use the string syntax:

```
var hierarchy = from p in ctx.Parents.Include("Children.GrandChild") select p;
```

Is the string syntax the only option, or is there some alternative way to use Lambda syntax in this situation?

Comment: I didnt know you could use a string in there.  That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Sure, you can do

```
var hierarchy = from p in ctx.Parents
                    .Include(p => p.Children.Select(c => c.GrandChild))
                select p;
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), caption Remarks, the fifth bullet.

Comment: To use the include method like this don't forget to reference `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: You can recursively continue this Select() pattern for descendants as well if the grandchild has children and so on.

Answer (score 45):

Update:
If you are using **Entity Framework Core** you should use the following syntax

```
var hierarchy = from p in ctx.Parents
                    .Include(p => p.Children)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.GrandChild)
                select p;
```

Comment: Note: In my case, for some weird reason intellisense wouldn't prompt me with the Grandchild object in the ".ThenInclude" lambda clause, but this was an edge case where intellisense was wrong and it didn't matter - the code still compiled.

Comment: What if you need to include the children of the GrandChild (aka GrandGrandChild)?

Comment: @Julen you can use .ThenInclude recursively for every nested child entity, like this: Parent.Include(child).ThenInclude(GrandChild).ThenInclude(GrandGrandChild) .. etc

Comment: How would you include two different grandchildren, say GrandSon and GrandDaughter?  Something starting like `ctx.Parents.Include(p => p.Children).ThenInclude(c => c.GrandSon)...`.  You couldn't add `ThenInclude(c => c.GrandDaughter)` because it would look in the GrandSon object for the GrandDaughter.

Comment: @SimonTewsi unfortunately the only way to do it right now is to `.Include` the top level a second time, then do another `.ThenInclude` with the other child you want to include.