# Include children and grandchildren when selecting from database

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have the following models

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Child> Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<GrandChild> GrandChild { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What Im trying to do now is select a list of parents from the database with the children and grandchildren.

Tried the following with no joy:

```
List<Parent> parent = new List<Parent>();
parent = db.parent.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Include` method:

```
parent = db.parent.Include(parent => parent.Child.Select(child => child.GrandChild)).ToList();
```

For older versions of Entity Framework, you have to use a string instead of a lambda expression:

```
parent = db.parent.Include("Child.GrandChild").ToList();
```

Or you can use the custom `Include` extension method I blogged about [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/).

Comment: Get the following error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @Ernie, you're probably using an older version of EF. See my updated answer.

Comment: Been trying with lambda expressions for awhile and couldnt figure out why its not working. Thanks for the help.

Comment: For EF Core, consider using the syntax from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38741905/1047812

Comment: is the .Include syntax for Eager Loading a guarantee that EF will load the relationships? would be good to know the circumstances under which it will load vs when it may be merely a hint... I cannot find any doco stating either way.

Answer (score 0):

in Linq to Sql you should use [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx)

```
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();

dlo.LoadWith<Parent>(p => p.Child );
dlo.LoadWith<Child>(c=> c.GrandChild );
db.LoadOptions = dlo;

List<Parent> parent = new List<Parent>();
parent = db.parent.ToList();
```