# How to include a item from a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, include

I try to get a list with the author. I tried this without success:

```cs
var user = await context.Users
    .Include(x => x.Notes)
    .Include(x => x.Notes).ThenInclude(x => x.Note)
    .Include(x => x.Notes.Select(x => x.Note.Author))
    .Include(x => x.Notes.Select(x => x.Note.Author)).ThenInclude(x => x.Notes.Select(x => x.Note.Author))
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.DiscordId == id)
.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

this are my classes:
**User.cs:**

```cs
public ulong DiscordId { get; set; }
public int Xp { get; set; }
public List<UserNote> Notes { get; set; } = new List<UserNote>();
```

**UserNote.cs:**

```cs
public int UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public User User { get; set; }
public int NoteId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("NoteId")]
public Note Note { get; set; }
```

**Note.cs:**

```cs
public int AuthorId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
public User Author { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

And I want in my query be able to use for example `user.Notes[0].Note.Author.Xp` as example.

Comment: Add result JSON as example. It is not clear which result is expected.

Comment: See if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801384/include-grandchildren-in-ef-query#answers-header