# How to include multiple child into Query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have table A, B , C, D, E, F with the relationship
A(parent) --> B ---> C (Part A)
A(parent) --> D --> E -- > F (Part B)

I'd refer the link below to get my answer but I am only able to get till E part B. I couldn't get until F

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905716/how-do-i-eagerly-include-the-child-and-grandchild-elements-of-an-entity-in-entit)!

Here is my code:

```
var query = db.tableA.Include(c => c.tableB.Select(b => b.tableC))                                                                                 
           .Include(d => d.tableD.Select(e => e.tableE));
```

Comment: As I understand `tableE` has relationship with `tableF` and you cannot include it. Am I right? If so, what is type of relationsip? *one-to-one*, *one-to-many* or something else?

Comment: Yes. I don't know how to include tableF. E-F (1 to many). F can be nullable.

Comment: just change second line in your code to `.Include(d => d.tableD.Select(e => e.tableE.Select(m => m.tableF)));`. It should help

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: yes. it work. thx. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I am adding it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It one `tableE` can have collection of `tableF` then you just need to add another select:

```
var query = db.tableA.Include(c => c.tableB.Select(b => b.tableC))
        .Include(d => d.tableD.Select(e => e.tableE.Select(m => m.tableF)));
```

If one `tableE` can have one `tableF` then you should write it as below:

```
var query = db.tableA.Include(c => c.tableB.Select(b => b.tableC))
        .Include(d => d.tableD.Select(e => e.tableE.tableF));
```